# Overlay for iproute2 - python library

Tags: linux, python, networking

I have heard that there is a python library which serves as an overlay (is it correct word? overlap?) for [`iproute2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2). I mean that it allows to use `iproute2` functions in `python` language. Is it [`pyroute2`](https://pypi.org/project/pyroute2/)? If not, do you happen to know what it could be?